# ListView sorting

Tags: c#, listview

How can i turn off ListView sort?

For some reason my ListView automatically sorts by asc on my first column.

Its a custom ListView but the only thing that has been modified is the actual look of it. Based 100% on the standard ListView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting:

```
myListView.Sorting = SortOrder.None;
```

Should do the trick, unless the items that you are adding to the `ListView` are already sorted.

Answer (score 1):

You've probably set the `ListView.Sorting` property to `SortOrder.Ascending`. Make sure it is set to `SortOrder.None`.