# Disable sorting listview

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I'm using a listview in a WinForm. With clicking on a column header the listview will be sorted.

Is it possible to disables this?

Comment: What form? WPF, WinForms, WebForms?

Comment: I'm using WinForms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms996467.aspx) is an article which describe how to implement sorting on listView.

Propably you must reomove event handler from ColumnClick event on listView.

Answer (score 2):

I would check this answer - [ListView sorting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12986553/listview-sorting)

.. but it does not disable sorting on click to any button. Solution to this would be creating own child that inherits from ListView, which will override the method for sorting, to not call base method => do nothing.

Also, You can add ListViewItemSorter and set it to null.

E.g.:

```
class MyListView : System.Windows.Forms.ListView
{
    public MyListView()
    {
        this.Sorting = System.Windows.Forms.SortOrder.None;
        this.ListViewItemSorter = null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I prefer the [`LVS_NOSORTHEADER`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774739#LVS_NOSORTHEADER) window style:

> Column headers do not work like buttons. This style can be used if clicking a column header in report view does not carry out an action, such as sorting.

Use something similar to this:

```
public class MyListView : 
    System.Windows.Forms.ListView
{
    protected override CreateParams CreateParams
    {
        get
        {
            var cp = base.CreateParams;
            cp.Style |= 0x8000; // LVS_NOSORTHEADER
            return cp;
        }
    }
}
```

Please note that you *cannot* use `SetWindowLong` to set the style after the control was created. [You can only use `LVS_NOSORTHEADER` upon control creation](http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?74926-LVS_NOSORTHEADER-in-CListCtrl&p=191971#post191971):

> The ListCtrl does not ignore the style, but some styles have an effect only at the time of creation of the control. So any changes to such styles after creation of the control will have no effect.